# Add Date Firebase Inside The Child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Database Image]

How Can I add date inside on that Child?

```
 @Override
public void onPositiveButtonClicked(final int value, final String comments) {
    //Get Rating and upload to Firebase
    final Rating rating = new Rating(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(),foodId,String.valueOf(value),comments);
    //User Can rate multiple times
    ratingDatabase.push().setValue(rating).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                   Toast.makeText(Food_Details.this, "Feedback Submmited! thanks", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
```

FireBase DAtabase:
*L43_Du94U5UMDTSPU62
  -comment: 
  -foodId
  -rateValue
  -userName:
*Date

The date is outside when I try to add

```
ratingDatabase.child("Date").setValue(ServerValue.TIME_STAMP);
```

The database is just creating another child but its outside. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First thing put in your mind when you want to set and update data in firebase then you need to create full reference to your parent node, Check below example

Following is the sequence of My DB Here I just want to set my latitude  longitude

- User

  - UserID

    - UserAddress

      - locationAddress

Here I want to set Location address as Latitude and Longitude, For that, I need to do the following logic

```
public void setValue(double lat,double lon){
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getReference().child("User").child("UserID").child("UserAddress").child("locationAddress");
        DatabaseReference latRef=databaseReference.child("latitude");
        DatabaseReference longRef=databaseReference.child("longitude");
        latRef.setValue(lat);
        longRef.setValue(lon);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
ratingDatabase = ratingDatabase.push();
ratingDatabase.child("Date").setValue(ServerValue.TIME_STAMP);
ratingDatabase.child("DATA").setValue(rating).addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
               Toast.makeText(Food_Details.this, "Feedback Submmited! thanks", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
});
```

Comment: i just did it like this 
ratingDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rating").push();
                Map userMap = new HashMap();
                userMap.put("comment", comments);
                userMap.put("foodId", foodId);
                userMap.put("rateValue", String.valueOf(value));
                userMap.put("userName", firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                userMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                ratingDatabase.setValue(userMap);
thanks for the help